# Drf: Update or create a model instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an attendance model that has a unique together constraint for date and user fk field, right now my implementation of the createorupdate is an if else that doesn't look nice:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user = validated_data.get('user', None)
    date = validated_data.get('date', None)

    if date is not None:
        user = Attendance.objects.filter(user=user, date=date).first()
        if user is not None:
            instance = Attendance.objects.update(
                user=validated_data['user'],
                presence=validated_data['presence'],
                leave_reason=validated_data['leave_reason'],
                date=validated_data['date'],
            )
            return instance
        else:
            instance = Attendance.objects.create(
                user=validated_data['user'],
                presence=validated_data['presence'],
                leave_reason=validated_data['leave_reason'],
                date=validated_data['date'],
            )
            return instance
```

This works the only issue is that the returned object from the update is null for all the fields and i need a better implementation example.

This is the full serializer:

```
class AttendanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
date = serializers.HiddenField(default=timezone.now)
leave_reason = serializers.CharField(required=False, default="")

class Meta:
    model = Attendance
    fields = ['user', 'presence', 'leave_reason', 'date'] #all the fields except pk
    extra_kwargs = {
        'user': {'required': True},
        'presence': {'required': True},
        'leave_reason': {'required': False},
    }
    # validators = [
    #     UniqueForYearValidator(
    #         queryset=Attendance.objects.all(),
    #         field='user',
    #         date_field='date',
    #         message=("You have already taken the attendance")
    #     )
    # ]

def create(self, validated_data):
    user = validated_data.get('user', None)
    date = validated_data.get('date', None)

    if date is not None:
        user = Attendance.objects.filter(user=user, date=date).first()
        if user is not None:
            instance = Attendance.objects.update(
                user=validated_data['user'],
                presence=validated_data['presence'],
                leave_reason=validated_data['leave_reason'],
                date=validated_data['date'],
            )
            return instance
        else:
            instance = Attendance.objects.create(
                user=validated_data['user'],
                presence=validated_data['presence'],
                leave_reason=validated_data['leave_reason'],
                date=validated_data['date'],
            )
            return instance
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm only familiar with the .update() after Attendace.objects.filter() and not after Attendance.objects. Maybe try this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user = validated_data.get('user', None)
    date = validated_data.get('date', None)

    if date is not None:
        user_var = Attendance.objects.filter(user=user, date=date).first()
        if user is not None:
            instance = user_var.update(
                user=validated_data['user'],
                presence=validated_data['presence'],
                leave_reason=validated_data['leave_reason'],
                date=validated_data['date'],
            )
            return instance
        else:
            instance = Attendance.objects.create(
                user=validated_data['user'],
                presence=validated_data['presence'],
                leave_reason=validated_data['leave_reason'],
                date=validated_data['date'],
            )
            return instance
```

Comment: 'Attendance' object has no attribute 'update'